# How do I configure eclipse to automatically refresh a project as part of it's build?

Tags: java, eclipse, build-process

I have a maven plugin generating some code for eclipse to build, but I have to manually refresh the project before eclipse sees the code.

How can I make eclipse automatically refresh the project as part of the build?

I'm trying to use a custom builder, but it wants to run a command (which I don't need to do).

Comment: A similar question exists and has a response : It is related to [Eclipse 3.7] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073348/auto-refresh-eclipse-project-upon-folder-update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make eclipse automatically refresh your whole workspace:
Window->Preferences->General->Workspace and check "Refresh automatically"

Comment: I think that only refreshes on startup and shutdown. I tried it and it did not automatically refresh it after I did a project / clean.

Comment: I use it daily, since I use ant-scripts and other external programs to modify the content of my workspace, and it works fine for me. I do however not know how it works; if it continuously polls the directory tree (and how often) or something smarter...

Comment: In Eclipse Indigo there are several options `Refresh on access` and `Refresh using native hooks or polling`.

Answer (score 3):

you can make it project/build specific for external builders under **Project Properties->Build->Refresh Policy**. Here is an example for C/C++ builds.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: That has been driving me crazy for a long time, I love you

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you run your Maven plugin, it may just refresh the project automatically. That is how it normally works in m2eclipse.

Also, you can configure a custom builder Project Properties / Builders / New... / Program and select some dummy command to run (e.g. C:\cygwin\bin\date.exe) and then configure project refresh settings.

Comment: I tried this, but It needs to work across platforms. I don't know that I can enter a dummy command that will work with Windows, Linux, and Mac OSX.

Comment: If you have cygwin installed on Windows, an sh script may work. But then again, how are you running your maven plugin in a first place?