# Auto refresh eclipse project upon folder update

Tags: eclipse, directory

I want to know if there is a way to enable auto refresh of eclipse project whenever there is an update on the folder consisting project files. For instance when i update the files from version control such as SVN,or if i include files from my friend etc. 
I know we can simply refresh the project or use SVN plug in as such ,but i am simply curious as to folder update notifications. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes , Eclipse version 3.7 has the new lightweight  refresh mechanism  to keep the workspace synchronized with the underlying filesystem. You can enable it in `Preferences > General > Workspace` and select `Refresh on access`.

[image]

If you use previous version , you can still use the old refresh mechanism  by selecting `Refresh using native hooks or polling`

---

**Reference:**

[What's New in eclipse 3.7](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html?path=0_6_0#Platform)

Comment: Although works when you modify file from explorer. it fails to work when files are updated from version control

Comment: for me,its already checked,yet my file system is not updates wiht my new code!

Comment: It worked for me, but it does slows down eclipse. may be because it keeps listening to native APIs

Comment: Using the setting Refresh using native hooks or polling worked for my case. I needed to refresh som resources genereted outside of Eclipse (without having to access them).

Answer (score 3):

Check "Refresh workspace on startup" in "General->Start up and Shutdown" preferences. That should fix it after application restart.