# Eclipse - Generated file not appearing in project folder

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto refresh eclipse project upon folder update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073348/auto-refresh-eclipse-project-upon-folder-update)

I have been working with Java projects using Eclipse (both Ganymede and Helios). I have noticed that when I generate a file, for instance if I create and write data to a text file, or if I serialize some objects, then although the file is visible if I search outside of eclipse (i.e. using windows explorer or the places on linux) it is not appearing in my project folder.

If I try and import this file into my project, then Eclipse tells me that I can't do this because the file is already in my project structure. So I have to move the file manually outside of this folder using windows explorer etc and then import it into the eclipse project before I can see it.

Is there a way to make these generated files appear automatically? What ias the reason they're not already doing so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

right click on the project -> refresh

or press F5

Answer (score 1):

Refresh your Eclispe project (F5).

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing those files programmatically, you might be interested in either Auto refresh as Beau suggested, or, if you can, [switch to the Eclipse IO API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5468283/60462) if you wish tighter integration with Eclipse, which will directly take care of this.