# File system not updated with new code Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, refresh, workspace

So I tried refreshing, closing and reopening, but my code that I changes in Eclipse has not reflected in the workspace folder when I view it using file explorer.

I also tried this [Auto refresh eclipse project upon folder update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073348/auto-refresh-eclipse-project-upon-folder-update)

What else could it be?

I use eclipse Luna 4.4.1 with OS X Yosemite.

Comment: refreshing, closing and reopening are generally used when you have made some edits outside eclipse and you want eclipse to be aware of them. In your case you have the opposite : changes in eclipse that aren't reflected outisde. Make sure you're checking the right directory in file explorer. Do you have any relevant error in `.medata/.log` in workspace directory ?

Comment: No errors in the log,I am checking the exact directory,and the only copy of my porject