# Where is the "Refresh Automatically" option in Eclipse Kepler for Mac?

Tags: eclipse

My Java project uses JRuby. The Ruby files I execute are resources within the project. I modify those files with an external editor (TextMate). Before I run the project, I need to refresh it. I was looking for a way to have the resources automatically refreshed whenever I run the project, with Eclipse Kepler on Mac:

---

- [How do I configure eclipse to automatically refresh a project as part of it's build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943961/how-do-i-configure-eclipse-to-automatically-refresh-a-project-as-part-of-its-bu)

The answer is `Window->Preferences->General->Workspace and check "Refresh automatically"`. However, there is no such thing as "Refresh automatically":

[image]

None of the checked options do what I was expecting.

---

- [Can Eclipse refresh resources automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212633/can-eclipse-refresh-resources-automatically)

> Settings > General > Workspace > Refresh On Access (aka Lightweight
>   Refresh). This preference causes Eclipse to automatically refresh
>   resources when it discovers that they're 'out-of-sync'.

No, that's not true. I run my project (without refreshing it) and Eclipse certainly did not refresh the resources.

> A single click on a project, a CTRL+A to select everything, and an F5
>   should do exactly what you need - refresh everything.

That's what I've been doing. I wouldn't call that "automatic".

---

- [Eclipse 'refresh automatically' and Maven build interference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108937/eclipse-refresh-automatically-and-maven-build-interference)

> I recently configured Eclipse (ver. 3.6) in order to make it
>   automatically refresh projects in the workspace (Windows > Preferences > General > Workspace > Refresh Automatically).

What is this mythical "Refresh Automatically" everybody is talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option was renamed to `Refresh using native hooks or polling` which is on the Preference page you show.

On the Mac I believe it using polling - so there will be a background thread periodically checking for updates.